# Difference between GIT pull request and merge from developer side

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull

There are two branches checked out on my local machine. 
Consider these are the branches name.

1. **feature/Sprint1703** (changes done in current sprint)
2. **develop** (the main branch from which feature/Sprint1703 has been checked out)

As per the regular procedure, **we do all the changes in feature/Sprint1703 and then raise a pull request to merge this branch to develop.**

What if we merge our code changes of feature/Sprint1703 branch directly to develop and push the develop branch which is in our local.
Isn't it similar to raise a pull request ?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the outcomes of the two scenarios you describe will be the same.  The pull request allows merging with oversight.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Yes, similar.

- Sometimes all developer doesn't have merge permission to the Default Branch. Then, the only procedure is to create a Pull request.
- Pull Request is a medium by which you can set `Reviewer` to show the code to your Team-Lead/Manager if all is ok.
- When Contributing any `upstream` (Other's repo), by Pull Request you can request to merge your changes in `upstream/master`. If upstream repo's author/authorized people want to take the feature, merge it with upstream/master or just skip/closed it.